# Inconsistent Jump Height in Unity character controller

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using unity's character controller to move my player around. This is the code that I use to handle gravity

```cs
    void HandleGravity() {
        
        if (IsGrounded() && Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
        {
      //      Debug.Log("Triggering jump");
            playerVelocity.y += Mathf.Sqrt(jumpHeight * -2f * walkGravity);
            isFlying = false;
        }
        playerVelocity.y += ((isFlying && playerVelocity.y < 0f) ? flightGravity : walkGravity) * Time.deltaTime;
        //   Debug.Log(playerVelocity);
        characterController.Move(playerVelocity);

    }
```

This is the code I'm using for checking the ground and determining whether or not the player is flying (which as you can probably tell from this is actually gliding):

```cs
    void HandleFlying() {
        bool currentIsFlying = Input.GetButton("Jump") && !Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && !IsGrounded();
        if (currentIsFlying != isFlying) {
            SetFlyingModel(currentIsFlying);
        }
        isFlying = currentIsFlying;
    }

    bool IsGrounded() {
        RaycastHit hit;
        return Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.down), out hit, 0.1f);
    }
```

The problem I'm seeing is that my player's jump height isn't consistent, sometimes it's a little higher than others (but not always). I'd like to remove gravity as a factor from the jump but I don't think this is possible as when I remove the multiplication by walkGravity from the jump, the player just hangs on the in the air in the position of the object they walked off of. I imagine that either my jump code contains some error or the gravity handling in general.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it using this logic:

```cs
    void HandleGravity(float horizontal, float vertical)
    {

        if (IsGrounded() && Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
        {
            //      Debug.Log("Triggering jump");
            playerVelocity.y += jumpHeight;
            isFlying = false;
            PlayJumpSound();
        }
        else
        {
            playerVelocity.y += ((isFlying && playerVelocity.y < 0f) ? flightGravity : walkGravity) * Time.deltaTime;
        }

        //   Debug.Log(playerVelocity);

        characterController.Move(playerVelocity * Time.deltaTime);

    }
```